# storing a string with '#' in it in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, special-characters

I tried storing a string in ***rails*** like

```
string = 'abc#$123'
```

but the string stores `"abc\ #$123"`. I tried removing "\" by using `string.delete("\",'')` but didn't work

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

This is correct, Ruby interpreter is just escaping the character `#$` by using backslash (`\`) character.

It is not exactly changing your string and adding the unwanted (`\`) character. You can verify this by doing `puts string` and it should print `abc#$123`

Answer (score 0):

The "\" is a way to **escape** the `#` character, which has a special meaning in ruby. So the "\" does not actually exist, it is just a convenience used by ruby to store your string value.

So, don't bother about it. You will see that **if you print** your string, **the "\" will magically disappear**.

```
irb(main):001:0> s = 'abc#$123'
=> "abc\#$123" # internal representation of your string
irb(main):002:0> print s
abc#$123=> nil # printed string value
```